# Stop scrolling display element after

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, progress-bar

I want to run **progressbar** animation with scroll.
But it runs several times instead of once
Excuse me if it's not correct.

Please help me.

**My code is:**

```
<div class="demo-5" data-percent="80">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        $('.demo-5').percentcircle({
            animate : true,
            diameter : 100,
            guage: 3,
            coverBg:'#fff',
            bgColor: '#efefef',
            fillColor: '#8BC163',
            percentSize: '48px',
            percentWeight: '50px'
         });
    });
});
</script>
  progressbar
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `percentcircle` seems to be a custom plugin. your code code is trying to initialize the plugin on `.demo-5` each time the `scroll` event is fired. this is not what you want to be doing. you need a way to update the `percentcircle` when a user scrolls a page. without knowing more about this plugin, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

A scroll event triggered every time a user scrolls to a different place in the element. In practice, it'll be triggered once for a smooth scrolling action, however if the scroll is 'jerky' or several small scrolls are made, this will trigger a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,
I haven't tested yet, but I hope it works,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(document).scroll(function(){
                        $('.demo-5').fadeIn(200);
                            $('.demo-5').percentcircle({
                            animate : true,
                            diameter : 100,
                            guage: 3,
                            coverBg:'#fff',
                            bgColor: '#efefef',
                            fillColor: '#8BC163',
                            percentSize: '48px',
                            percentWeight: '50px'
                             });
                            setTimeout(function()
                            { 
                            $('.demo-5').fadeOut(1000);
                             }, 500);
                        });
                    });
```